# can anyone tell the oracle sql query for converting 10 digit number into words?

Tags: sql, oracle

can anyone tell the oracle sql query for converting 10 digit number into words? 
 for example I have numbers like 9876543210 and i would to convert 
these numbers as NINE EIGHT SEVEN SIX FIVE FOUR THREE TWO ONE ZERO.

Comment: I doubt there is an Oracle function for this purpose.  You can write your own.

Comment: Why would you want to do that?  SQL is no place for doing such a thing.

Comment: https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:18305103094123

Comment: i was asked in an interview

Comment: please help me out

Comment: Is the interview **ongoing**? Are you going back to meet with the interviewer and share with them the answer you received on this web site? What are they interested in - your ability to ask questions on SO?

Comment: no im back to home.. guys please help with this or leave it PLEASE DONT MAKE FUN OF IT

Answer (score 2):

Actually, for this purpose, you can use a bunch of `replace()`s:

```
select replace(replace(. . . . replace(col, '0', 'ZERO '
                                      ), '1', 'ONE '
       . . .
       )
```

You'll need 10, one for each digit.  You might want to throw in a `TRIM()` after the last one to remove the final space.

Comment: sorry cant understand please elaborate your answer with patience

Answer (score 1):

```
with    num  (n) as 
        (
            select  9876543210 
            from    dual
        )

       ,dict (digit,descr) as 
        (
            select  substr(column_value,1,1) as digit
                   ,substr(column_value,3)   as description 

            from    table
                    (
                        sys.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST 
                        (
                            '0 ZERO','1 ONE','2 TWO','3 THREE','4 FOUR','5 FIVE','6 SIX','7 SEVEN','8 EIGHT','9 NINE'
                        )
                    ) t
        )

select  listagg ((select d.descr from dict d where d.digit = n.digit),' ') 
            within group (order by i) as digits

from   (select      level                      as i
                   ,substr(to_char(n),level,1) as digit
        from        num
        connect by  level <= length(to_char(n))
        ) n
```

---

```
+---------------------------------------------------+
|                      DIGITS                       |
+---------------------------------------------------+
| NINE EIGHT SEVEN SIX FIVE FOUR THREE TWO ONE ZERO |
+---------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: im getting error : ERROR at line 1:
ORA-32033: unsupported column aliasing

Comment: This is a tested code Works "as is" on Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production